# Can you post worked Electrical questions?

Tags: discussion

I am not sure if i am asking in the right place however, i'd just like to know this information.

I have completed a question and have calculated an answer however there is no way for me to know if the gained answer is accurate or if i have a flaw in the method, can i post for users to verify the method? would like to prevent being marked down.

Comment: @Wossname i tried to change however i do not have enough reputation as yet.

Comment: The moderators can move this question for you

Comment: That would be appreciated

Comment: There is already a system in place to give an indication if the answer is accurate or not. Answers can be up or down voted. Also look at the reputation of the user writing the answer.

Comment: Generally, if you post a question and what you have attempted, someone will check/verify your work.  Homework without an attempt at an answer is usually locked.

Comment: thank-you all for making this issue clear

Comment: Your title makes no sense.  What is a "worked" electrical question?

Comment: @OlinLathrop I'm not sure where the confusion is?  an electrical problem that i for example have solved and have a solution in form of a value or conclusion, and with this i post on this site for users to comment on the accuracy of my method for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is conceptually not different from a high quality homework question. In fact, questions like this would serve as good examples on *how* to write a good homework question - they contain all the steps you have taken so far.

Therefore, I conclude that **yes**, you can post homework questions containing the answer. By definition, since you want another opinion, it shows that you don't know if you have the right answer or not, and as such, need guidance.

#### ...but

That doesn't mean you can post whatever trivial question you see fit. Hopefully the voting system will take care of sorting out junk, as it does today with every other type of question. If your question can be answered with "Yes.", it's a lousy question.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't want to do homework for other people, it deprives them of valuable learning. I've even seen a few people posting exam questions and even one question that appeared to be an in class quiz question of a snapshot of the board where the OP was asking for a *quick* solution (presumably before the quiz was done. These types of questions are offensive to me, because a student shouldn't be only concerned with the end result (the answer) but should be interested in the process of learning and how to come up with the correct answer.

If your going to post any question, make sure you take the time to format it and put some thought into it, instead of posting a question right out of the book\assignment.

However if you have a homework problem and prove that your working on it and your stuck I don't have a problem with answering that type of question provided that you've shown your attempt. SE is a site for students:

> This site is for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts. We ask and answer questions about electrical and electronics engineering topics, which include electronics, physical computing, and those working with microcontrollers, Arduinos and embedded systems.